# Data from serial port is cut after 8 characters

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have an electronic scale that sends a weight value every second to a Raspberry 4 via a serial port.

When listening to the port with the `minicom` program, everything looks fine. The output looks like this:

```
      922 g     
      922 g     
      922 g
```

(There are spaces before and after the actual value. 6 before and 5 after.)

However, when trying to obtain the same data with a custom Python script, the data is cut after 8 characters and looks like this:

```
      92
2 g     


      92
2 g     


      92
2 g
```

This is a problem because when I try to use this data further down my app, I only ever have access to the second line (the first one is immediately overwritten by the second one), so instead of "922 g", I only get "2 g".

Here is the script I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
import re

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttySC1',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
)

while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    if x:
        print(x)
```

I tried changing the baud rate on the scale (and in the script) but it doesn't change anything.

Do you have any idea of what could be causing this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the python script shown the one used to generate the output? In theory the regular expression should have removed the whitespace and the 'g' character. What do you get if you put a `print(x)` before you apply the regular expression?

Comment: Also - try setting the timeout to a positive number so that `readline()` doesn't get the chance to return immediately before it's received the newline character.

Comment: @cguk70 Sorry, my mistake. The regular expression was in a previous version of the script. The output shown is the script without the regular expression. I've updated my code (removed this line). (To clarify: WITH the regular expression, the output is still on two lines: "92" and "2 g". Just without spaces.)

Comment: @cguk70 thanks for the suggestion (timeout). I can't test it right now but I will on Monday. The timeout is expressed in seconds, right? So 1 should be enough.

Comment: Yes - when the timeout is set to zero - it is non-blocking - so what could be happening is if there is a small delay in the sender sending the characters, the `readline()` call could be exiting prematurely and you would see exactly what you're seeing. Setting it to 1 second should be fine - if your application is able to handle a 1 second delay when there's no data - otherwise you could try reducing to half a second. But try with a larger timeout first.

Comment: @cguk70 Thanks. Reading this page: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html, it says: "timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed) returns immediately _when the requested number of bytes are available_, otherwise wait (…)". What is the _requested number of bytes_ and how can I change it? Is it possible that it's currently at 8 (default?), explaining why the output is cut after 8 characters?

Comment: But you're doing `readline()` which does multiple `read()` calls until the newline character is detected. You shouldn't have to worry about the size unless you want to stop reading after a fixed number of characters if the newline isn't found. `readline()` is explained better in the [pySerial Short Introduction](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) section. I really think increasing the timeout will solve your issue.